# jQuery doesn't give a proper output, but gives these

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
(function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var mref = 'http://www.someprivatelink.net';
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(title1);
    var title1 = $('#node-264152').find('.audio-description').html();
    alert(title1);
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = title1;
a.href = mref;
document.body.appendChild(a);
})();
```

I'm using this script to add an download link to the bottem of my page wich doesn't to to be permanent so I enter it via console with Google Chrome.

The ID and the Class are correct to the value I need to extract, I've added the alert to check if the fault was in the HTML or in my javascript.

The output at the bottem of the page has the value of 'Undefined', while it has to be 'Log moving along in body of water 2'

But the alert does display ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O160f.png)) this message with a few boxxes before and after the message, I think this is causing the undefined error.

Is there any solution my var can be converted into only text?

Thanks in advance, Tjalle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `title1` before it's defined. swap the lines

```
var title1   = $('#node-264152').find('.audio-description').html();
var linkText = document.createTextNode(title1);
```

Should be noted that since you're already using jQuery, you could do

```
var title1 = $('#node-264152').find('.audio-description').html();

$('<a />', {
   href  : 'http://www.someprivatelink.net',
   title : title1,
   text  : title1
}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: wow, only see it now, seems stupid of me now I finally see it, thank you!